# Dagger Circular Dependency Deadlock

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

Is it possible for Dagger to deadlock while providing for dependencies? For example, there is a circular dependency between Class A and Class B because both inject each other like this:

```
class ClassA @Inject constructor(classB: Provider<ClassB>) {
   fun logSomeMetrics() {
      // ...
      classB.get().writeSomething();
      // ...
   }
}

class ClassB @Inject constructor(classA: Provider<ClassA>) {
   fun writeSomething() {
      // ...
      classA.get().logSomeMetrics();
      // ...
   }
}
```

I used Provider<> to try to break the circular dependency. But is there ever a race condition or scenario where two threads will deadlock because one is trying to resolve dependency (lazily through `get()`) for Class A, while the other is trying to resolve dependency (lazily through `get()`) for Class B?

Or is it guaranteed that both dependencies will be resolved properly without deadlock?

Comment: This question was asked as [google/dagger#4003](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/4003) and received an answer there from Dagger maintainer Eric Chang.